# Hominem super hominem

Tags: medieval-latin, sentence-translation

I'm really struggling with a passage in a 12th century manuscript extolling the virtues of studying astrology that I'm working on for my thesis. The sentence is:

> *De huius utilitate autem superfluum esset agere cum ista hominem super hominem efferens futuraram ac omnium a natura absconditorum precium efficiat.*

The previous sentences explained that though its study was hard work, it was worthwhile, and this sentence is expanding on that. I'm confused as to what the subject and object are in the sentence — *efficiat* seems to be the main verb and I assume that *precium* (reward) is the object. I'm also assuming that *superfluum* is a noun (surplus) here, and Whitaker's tells me that *agere* with *cum* means "spends time" rather than its usual meaning (though does that mean *cum* doesn't take the ablative in that case, because I can't see an ablative here?).

My attempt at translating it is pretty muddled — I have something along these lines:

> Concerning the usefulness of this surplus would be to spend time so
>   that a man over man brings out the [events of the] future, and all
>   hidden things by birth/nature are its reward.

I think the gist of it is that it's worth spending time studying because the reward is the ability to see hidden and future events, but I'm puzzling about the structure of the sentence.

*Hominem super hominem* is confusing me in particular — I know super takes the accusative, but why is the first *hominem* also accusative? Is it somehow the object of *efficiat*?

Any suggestions very gratefully accepted!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice question. I made some formatting edits, but feel free to undo or redo any of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word *futuraram* is not well-formed: the closest correct form is *futurarum* (feminine genitive plural) but actually *futurorum* (masculine genitive plural) is the only form that seems to make sense in context to me. It is possible that it means *futurarum [rerum]* ("of future things")--a phrase often used by Cicero, without the ellipsis--but it comes out to the same thing. It's a moot point, unless you have access to the actual manuscript.

I found an M.Phil. dissertation by Nicholas Whyte which transcribes it in this same way, so I suspect that you may have taken it from there. Either way, it is most certainly a typo, or the work of someone who does not understand Latin.

Amending thus:

> De huius utilitate autem superfluum esset agere cum ista hominem super hominem efferens futurorum ac omnium a natura absconditorum precium efficiat.

The reading is fairly straightforward with this amendment:

> But it would be unnecessary to speak of the utility of this thing [= astrology], since it brings about the reward of [knowing] future things and all things that are hidden from nature, elevating man above man.

This is classic *praetermissio* in the style of Cicero: "I will not speak of X, since it is so obvious...but here you go anyway!"

Some notes:

- *agere de aliquo* means "to treat about something"
- *cum* is introducing a causal relation: "since, because". In this use, it takes the present subjunctive, *efficiat*
- *effero* means to "elevate": in this case, it means to "elevate man above man" = "allow man to exceed his natural abilities". This is a participle, modifying *ista*, independent of what comes after.
- *pretium +* genitive + *efficere* means "to bring the reward of..." In my reading, "knowledge" is understood.

Comment: Alternatively to _futurorum_ might be _futurarum … absconditarum_, with an implied _rerum_.

Comment: Alternatively:  hominem super hominem efferens could mean "elevating one man over another".

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Brian! Yes, I'm working on the same text that Nicholas Whyte did (and we're in touch with each other). He did his MPhil 25 years ago, and transcribed (but didn't translate) some of the prologue, from which this is taken. And you're absolutely right about it being futurorum - Whyte gives it as "futuraram" as it's very unclear in one manuscript, but it's very clearly "futurorum" in another (I'm fortunate enough to have three different copies of the text in three manuscripts).

Comment: I had sort of assumed an implied "rerum" (which I rather clumsily put as "[events of the]" in my attempted translation. Your explanations - and translation - make perfect sense, so thank you so much for replying.